# Ingresar nombres en java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa que capture nombres y calificaciones, se pueden ingresar cuantas calificaciones quieres pero no debe de haber sacado una calificacion mayor de 10. Sin embargo mi programa no esta dejando que ingrese el nombre del alumno. Cual es el error?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Calificaciones{
   public static void main (String[]args){
      Scanner entrada;
      entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner entrada2;
      entrada2=new Scanner(System.in);

      String nombre;
      int opcion_menu=0; int ejecutar=0; int calificacion; 
      int x=0; 
      int promedio;  
      int otro=0;

      do{
         System.out.println("Eliga la opcion deseada \n 1.Captura \n 2.Consulta \n 3.Salida ");
         opcion_menu=entrada.nextInt();
         if(opcion_menu==1)
         {
            System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del alumno");
            nombre=entrada.nextLine();
           do{
            System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion:");
            calificacion=entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Otro? \n 1.Si \2.No");
            otro=entrada.nextInt();
            }while(otro !=2);

         }
      }while (ejecutar !=0);

   }
}
```

Comment: Introduces '1' cuando te pide la "Opcion deseada"?

Comment: Si. 1 es para la captura de alumnos que es donde tengo que poner nombre y calificacion

Comment: No te deja ni una sola vez introducir el nombre?

Comment: El valor `ejecutar` está en cero, por lo tanto no entraría al ciclo `do...while`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave En `do...while` entra como mínimo una vez, independientemente del valor de la condición `while`

Answer (score 1):

La condición del primer do-while es la que solo te deja entrar una vez, `ejecutar` siempre vale cero y te estas preguntando mientras sea diferente de cero sigue ejecutándose, podrías cambiar dentro del while que `ejecutar == 0` y poner una condición de  que si `opcion_menu == 3` cambiar `ejecutar = 1` por ejemplo.